# What are the "values" in the substrate Merkle Patricia tree?

Tags: storage, trie

I've read Shawn's [substrate storage deep dive](https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate/substrate-storage-deep-dive/) recently. It is very informative and I *roughly* understand different key systems exist and how the keys are caclulated.

However, one thing that puzzles me is what exactly is stored in the trie. It's mentioned in the presentation that the key of KVDB is actually the hash of "trie node", which is a serialized struct object including header, partial key, "value" and so on. But what is the value here? It can't be the SCALE-encoded storage value, can it? (for example, the value in `StorageValue`) Otherwise how can I query the database if the key calculation includes the value which I don't even know yet? And I assume updating the value isn't supposed to change the key.

But on the other hand, if the trie node doesn't have the real value information, where is it stored? It must exist somewhere such that the merkle state root involves it. Eventually it's probably stored as the value in KVDB, but where is it located in the trie?

Answer (score 0):

> But what is the value here? It can't be the SCALE-encoded storage value, can it? (for example, the value in StorageValue)

The value in the KVDB is indeed the SCALE-encoded value.

> Otherwise how can I query the database if the key calculation includes the value which I don't even know yet? And I assume updating the value isn't supposed to change the key.

When you walk the trie you're right that you don't know the value yet, or it's hash. Instead, you query by its 'storage key', which is either hardcoded e.g. for the runtime code, or the path to the information you want, e.g. "PalletBalances -> Balances -> Address123".

> But on the other hand, if the trie node doesn't have the real value information, where is it stored?

It's stored in the KVDB, which the trie node points to.

---

You might find this lesson from PBA enlightening https://polkadot-blockchain-academy.github.io/pba-book/substrate/storage/page.html